# Proofs Related to the Fibonacci Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

I need to prove several proofs related to the Fibonacci sequence and I don't have the faintest clue how to do so. Please help!

Given that the Fibonacci sequence is defined as $f_n = f_{n-1} + f_{n-2}$ for $n \ge 3 $

I need to prove that:

$$\frac 1{f_{n-1}f_{n+1}} = \frac 1{f_{n-1}f_n} - \frac 1{f_nf_{n+1}}$$

and that

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac 1 {f_{n-1}f_{n+1}} = 1$$

and that

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac {f_n} {f_{n-1}f_{n+1}} = 2$$

Any help whatsoever you could give me would be appreciated. Even just hints as how to approach these problems. Anything you can give me.

Comment: I don't have access to paper so I can help you specifically but you need to rewrite one side of each equation using the definition of a Fibonacci term until you can make one side look like the other.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: rewrite $f_{n+1} = f_{n} + f_{n-1}$ for all 3.

First equation:
$$\frac{1}{f_{n-1}(f_n f_{n-1})} = \frac{1}{f_{n-1}f_n } - \frac{1}{f_n(f_n + f_{n-1})}$$

Third equation, use:

$$\frac{f_n}{f_{n-1}f_{n+1}} = \frac{1}{f_{n-1}}-\frac{1}{f_{n+1}}$$